# Duplicity and Google Drive

Tags: duplicity

Is it there a way to make duplicity backups to Google Drive?

As far as I understand, WebDav and FTP are not supported by Google Drive. But maybe there is an extension to duplicity in the works?

Answer (score 1):

The only way (IMO) would be to configure a Windows system with Google Drive (there's no Linux client yet, not sure about OSX), share the Google Drive folder, and then mount it on your target *nix system with Samba and use it as a backup target.

It would be convoluted, prone to errors and breakage, and probably perform pretty badly. But you *could*, if you *really* had to.

Answer (score 1):

There used to be a [plugin for GoogleDocs](https://code.launchpad.net/~carlos-abalde/duplicity/google-docs) ([announcement](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/duplicity-talk/2011-07/msg00068.html)), but that one seems to have stopped working at the time GoogleDrive was introduced. I shortly looked into it, and it seems to me that some of the Google GData client libraries (which the plugin uses) still need to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

[This guy](http://ptspts.blogspot.com/2012_08_01_archive.html) seems to have it figured out. When I tried on Ubuntu 11.10, I had an earlier version of duplicity than what he uses. I updated to v0.6.19, and it works like a charm.